# Why does c++ assert() falsely call abort() when comparing a negative int to an unsigned int?

Tags: c++, integer, assert, unsigned

I have found in my c++ program that assert() calls abort() in a case similiar to the following code snippet:

```
int a = -1;
unsigned int b = 5;

assert(a < b);
```

As a human I can tell that -1 is definitely smaller than 5, regardless of the fact that one is an int and the other an unsigned int. Why can't the compiler?

I have already found the solution, which is that this assert is just nonsensical since an unsigned will always be positive (I had kind of forgotten that the variable in my actual code was an unsigned), but I am just curious as to why this happens.

Comment: Your compiler should have warned you about comparing variables of different signed"ness". Did it? When comparing variables best always cast the values to the same signed or unsigned. Do mind that this may truncate values.

Comment: Well the human is wrong here. You're comparing unsigned and signed here which means the result is converted to an **unsigned** integral type and since the conversion of `-1` to unsigned yields the largest possible value, you're applying the first parameter of the comparison is greater after this conversion. Your compiler very likely warns you about this issue btw.

Comment: When comparing an `int` with an `unsigned`, the `int` is converted to `unsigned` first, and then the converted value is compared.    Converting `-1` to `unsigned` gives the maximum value an `unsigned` can represent - which is greater than `5`.

Comment: The a variable is casted to a (very large) unsigned int before the comparison is executed

Comment: Try [`assert(std::cmp_less(a, b));`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp)

Comment: @Enlico Indeed. I didn't know about it myself a week ago.

Comment: Do you have warnings enabled?  I'm seeing `warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-compare]`

Comment: duplicates: [Why sizeof(int) is not greater than -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24466857/995714), [Signed/unsigned comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5416414/995714), [C++ Bigger than oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19349480/995714), [why is -1>strlen(t) true in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30295512/995714), [Why is (sizeof(int) > -1) false? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34151309/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is comparing signed and unsigned integer safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646743/is-comparing-signed-and-unsigned-integer-safe)

Answer (score 4):

When you compare a signed integer with an unsigned integer, the compiler implicitly converts the signed value into unsigned, so essentially:

```
int a = -1;
unsigned int b = 5;

assert(a < b);
```

is equivalent to:

```cpp
assert(static_cast<unsigned>(-1) < static_cast<unsigned>(5));
```

Now, because unsigned integers cannot hold negative values, `-1` wraps up back to [`UINT_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/climits) due to [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow):

```cpp
assert(UINT_MAX < static_cast<unsigned>(5));
```

which is obviously false, since `UINT_MAX` is larger than 5, so the assertion fails.

Comment: The number -1 wrapping to UINT_MAX isn't a consequence of 2's complement.